# Excel VBA: Finding column number of Nth field name

Tags: excel, vba

I have a function where I specify the field I want and the header row number and it returns the column. E.g. `=findField("Region",1)` would return the column number containing the header "Region". This worked well until I encountered a report containing duplicate names in the header row. E.g. instead of 1st and last name it would have "Name" for both fields so I needed to specify the occurrence I wanted as in `=findField("Name",1,2)` for the 2nd occurrence. I came up with a solution but it has 2 issues. The first is that if the field is in the first column it won't work properly. E.g. if columns A and B have "Name" then `=findField("Name",1,1)` would return the second field instead of the first and `=findField("Name",1,2)` would wrap around and return the 1st which is not what I want. The second issue is that it wraps around which I would prefer it not to do at all. What I came up with is as follows:

```
Function findField2(fieldName As String, Optional rowStart As Long = 0, Optional occurrence As Long = 1)
    Dim Found As Range, lastRow As Long, count As Integer, myCol As Long

    If rowStart = 0 Then rowStart = getHeaderRow()
    myCol = 1

    For count = 1 To occurrence
        Set Found = Rows(rowStart).Find(what:=fieldName, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole, After:=Cells(rowStart, myCol))

        If Found Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox "Error: Can't find '" & fieldName & "' in row " & rowStart
            Exit Function
        Else
            myCol = Found.Column
        End If
    Next count

    lastRow = Cells(Rows.count, Found.Column).End(xlUp).Row
    findField2 = Found.Column
```

What do I need to do to allow for the field being in column A? Putting in 0 for myCol doesn't work. The initial finding function was based off https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/629346-vba-finding-text-row-1-return-column.html and I was tweaking it to suit my needs.

Thanks,
Ben

Comment: Your best bet would be to use the last cell in the row as your start for the `After` parameter

Comment: @BigBen `myCol` updates as the loop progresses but Yes some reworking would be needed

Comment: Only for the initial `Find()`.  There's also currently nothing to stop the Find() looping back, so it will return a "10th" value even if there are only 3 present.

Answer (score 1):

Here's something not using `Find()` which should still meet your goals:

```
Function findField2(fieldName As String, Optional rowStart As Long = 0, _
                                           Optional occurrence As Long = 1)
    Dim a, rw As Range, m

    If rowStart = 0 Then rowStart = getHeaderRow()

    With ActiveSheet 'might be better to pass the sheet as a parameter
        Set rw = Application.Intersect(.Rows(rowStart), .UsedRange)
        a = .Evaluate("=IF(" & rw.Address & "=""" & fieldName & _
                            """,COLUMN(" & rw.Address & "),FALSE)")
    End With

    m = Application.Small(a, occurrence) 'find the n'th match (will return an error if none)

    If IsError(m) Then MsgBox "No occurrence #" & occurrence & " of '" & _
                              fieldName & "' on row# " & rowStart, vbExclamation

    findField2 = IIf(IsError(m), 0, m)
End Function

Sub Tester()
    Debug.Print findField2("A", 5, 40)
End Sub
```

Comment: What 'getHeaderRow()'?

Comment: @YasserKhalil  I have no idea - it's in the OP's code though.  The `rowStart` parameter is optional, sio I'd guess it provides a default value for that.

Comment: @YasserKhalil getHeaderRow() is a function I wrote to work out the header row in the sheet if it isn't specified as a function parameter. It works out the last row/column and then based on the last column searches down from the 1st row until it hits a non-empty cell.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Can you provide us with the function to have a look?

Comment: @YasserKhalil I provided the function at the end of the answer I just posted.

Comment: @TimWilliams In your code does m become a variant type since nothing is specified?

Comment: I didn't find it ..I am sorry for disturbing you

Comment: @YasserKhalil I had edited it in to my response afterwards and checking now it wasn't there. I have edited my response again to include the function.

Comment: @Ben - yes it's purposely a variant.

Answer (score 0):

## Found-in-row Column feat. the Wrap Around Issue

No object references here i.e. everything refers to the `ActiveSheet` (of the `ActiveWorkbook`).

### Find (After)

By **default** the **Find** method starts the search from the next cell (6. **SearchDirection** `xlNext` or `1`) of the supplied cell range parameter of the After argument (2. **After**) i.e. in case you use cell `A1` by row (5. **SearchOrder** `xlByRows` or `1`), the search will start from `B1`, continue until the last column, wrap around and continue with `A1` last. Therefore the **last** cell of the row has to be used to start the search with the **first** cell `A1`.

### Wrap Around

The **Wrap Around issue** is solved with an `If` statement only if the Occurrence Number is greater than 1. If no occurrence was found, `0` is returned.
The column number of the found cell (`intCol`) is passed to a variable (`intWrap`) and every next occurrence of the value, they are checked against each other. Now, if the variable is equal to the column number, the function returns `-1`, indicating that the value was found but the specified occurrence has not been found.

```
'*******************************************************************************
' Purpose:    Finds the Nth occurrence of a value in cells of a row            * 
'             to return the column number of the cell where it was found.      *
'*******************************************************************************
' Inputs                                                                       *
'   FindValue:          The value to search for.                               *
'   FindRow:            The row to search in.                                  *
'   OccurrenceNumber:   The occurrence number of the value to search for.      *
'*******************************************************************************
' Returns:    The column number of the Nth occurrence of the value.           *
'              0 if value was not found.                                       *
'             -1 if value was found, but not the specified occurrence of it.   *
'             -2 if worksheet has no values (-4163).                           *
'             -3 if workbook is add-in (No ActiveSheet).                       *
'*******************************************************************************
Function FoundinrowColumn(FindValue As Variant, Optional FindRow As Long = 0, _
    Optional OccurrenceNumber As Integer = 1) As Integer

  Dim intCol As Integer     ' Search Start Column Number
  Dim intCount As Integer   ' OccurrenceNumber Counter
  Dim intWrap As Integer    ' Wrap Around Stopper

  ' Check if ActiveSheet exists.
  If ActiveSheet Is Nothing Then FoundinrowColumn = -3: Exit Function
  ' Check if sheet has no values.
  If Cells.Find("*", Cells(Rows.count, Columns.count), -4163, 1, 1) _
      Is Nothing Then FoundinrowColumn = -2: Exit Function

  ' Find first used row if no FindRow parameter.
  If FindRow = 0 Then
    FindRow = Cells.Find("*", Cells(Rows.count, Columns.count)).Row
  End If
  ' Set initial Search Start Column Number.
  intCol = Columns.count

  ' Try to find the Nth occurence of 'FindValue' in 'FindRow'.
  For intCount = 1 To OccurrenceNumber
    If Not Rows(FindRow).Find(FindValue, Cells(FindRow, intCol)) Is Nothing Then
      intCol = Rows(FindRow).Find(FindValue, Cells(FindRow, intCol)).Column
      If intCount > 1 Then
        If intCol = intWrap Then FoundinrowColumn = -1: Exit Function
       Else
        intWrap = intCol
      End If
     Else
      FoundinrowColumn = 0: Exit Function
    End If
  Next

  FoundinrowColumn = intCol

End Function
'*******************************************************************************
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your responses. I am picking up useful techniques which is of great help. I actually fixed the first issue based on @TimWilliams to set myCol to the last column so it starts the find at the first column and added a check for the wrap around per the below. I also changed the msgBox to return a value instead per @VBasic2008.

```
Function findField2(fieldName As String, Optional rowStart As Long = 0, Optional occurrence As Long = 1)
    Dim Found As Range, lastRow As Long, count As Integer, myCol As Long

    If rowStart = 0 Then rowStart = getHeaderRow()
    myCol = 16384

    For count = 1 To occurrence
        Set Found = Rows(rowStart).Find(what:=fieldName, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole, After:=Cells(rowStart, myCol))

        ' Check if nothing found or for wrap around and Nth occurrence not found
        If Found Is Nothing Or count > 1 And Found.Column <= myCol Then
            findField2 = 0
            Exit Function
        Else
            myCol = Found.Column
        End If
    Next count


    lastRow = Cells(Rows.count, Found.Column).End(xlUp).Row
    findField2 = Found.Column
End Function
```

Here is the getHeaderRow function mentioned in the findField function above:

```
Function getHeaderRow() As Long
    Dim i As Long, lastCol As Long, lastRow As Long
    lastCol = Cells.Find("*", [a1], , , xlByColumns, xlPrevious).Column
    lastRow = Cells.Find("*", [a1], , , xlByRows, xlPrevious).Row
    i = 1

    Do While Cells(i, lastCol).Value = ""
        i = i + 1
        If i > lastRow Then
            i = 0
            Exit Do
        End If
    Loop

    getHeaderRow = i
End Function
```

Comment: Might be worth having a look at `FindNext` to find anything after the first occurrence.

Comment: If your sheet is blank `lastCol` will try and return row 0 which will throw an `Object variable or With block variable not set` error.  Have a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-in-finding-last-used-cell-in-vba)  for some examples of finding the last cell.

Answer (score 0):

This version uses `FindNext` to search for occurrences after the first.
It searches `Sheet1` of the workbook that the code is in (`ThisWorkbook`):

```
Sub Test()

    Dim MyCell As Range

    'Second occurrence default row.
    Set MyCell = FindField("Date", Occurrence:=3)

    If Not MyCell Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Found in cell " & MyCell.Address & "." & vbCr & _
            "Row: " & MyCell.Row & vbCr & "Column: " & MyCell.Column & vbCr & _
            "Sheet: '" & MyCell.Parent.Name & "'" & vbCr & _
            "Workbook: '" & MyCell.Parent.Parent.Name & "'", vbOKOnly + vbInformation
    Else
        MsgBox "Value not found."
    End If

End Sub

Public Function FindField(FieldName As String, Optional RowStart As Long = 0, _
    Optional Occurrence As Long = 1) As Range

    Dim rFound As Range
    Dim x As Long
    Dim sFirstAdd As String

    If RowStart = 0 Then RowStart = 1
    x = 1

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Rows(RowStart)
        Set rFound = .Find( _
            What:=FieldName, _
            LookIn:=xlValues, _
            LookAt:=xlWhole, _
            After:=.Cells(RowStart, .Columns.Count))

        If Not rFound Is Nothing Then
            Set FindField = rFound
            If Occurrence <> 1 Then
                sFirstAdd = rFound.Address
                Do
                    Set rFound = .FindNext(rFound)
                    x = x + 1

                Loop While x <> Occurrence And rFound.Address <> sFirstAdd
                If rFound.Address = sFirstAdd Then
                    Set FindField = Nothing
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End With

End Function
```